# HG532e Login Script Python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, scrape

I'm trying to login to my ADSL modem page so that I can see connected hosts and reboot the modem when I run the script but until now I couldn't even login to the modem page.
Here is my code so far :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

payload = {
    'Username': 'topadmin',
    'Password': 'topadmin'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://192.168.1.1/', data=payload)  
    print (p.status_code) 
    print (p.text)
    r = s.get('http://192.168.1.1/')
    print (r.text)
```

Here is my Modem HTML page [(SourcePage)](https://repl.it/@MohamedAli6/Modem)

PS: After I login with my browser I get this page address: `http://192.168.1.1/html/content1.asp`

> And here is its [Sourcepage2](https://repl.it/@MohamedAli6/Modem)

Comment: What kind of help do you expect from us?

Comment: i need you to help me to connect to the modem page . so i can get the connected users and reboot modem

Comment: So, you want *us* to do all the reverse engineering for you, without the hardware?

Comment: The easy way: `selenium`. The hard way: examine the js code and http traffic.

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks i will try with selenium